# Change key index in dictionary with lists Py3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

I have got dict like this:

```py
dict = {1: [x, y, z], 2: [x1, y1, z1]}
```

further I add another key '1e' to dict and it becomes like this:

```py
dict = {1: [x, y, z], 2: [x1, y1, z1], '1e': [x2, y2, z2]}
```

in the end I need dict in order 1, 1e, 2.

so the expected result must be like that:

```py
dict = {1: [x, y, z], '1e': [x2, y2, z2],2: [x1, y1, z1]}
```

how can I change index of 1e from 2 to 1?

p.s.: x value is date as a str, tried to use order by value x with different methods but nothing works. returns an error that float and str can't be sorted.
I've tried smh like this:

```py
new_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
```

and that:

```py
new_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1],'%Y-%m-%d'), reverse=True)
```

in the second method error is to find strptime.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

To change the order of keys, you need to re-create the dictionary from its items sorted in the desired order:

```
d = {1: ["x", "y", "z"], 2: ["x1", "y1", "z1"], '1e': ["x2", "y2", "z2"]}

d = dict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda k:str(k[0])))

print(d)
{1: ['x', 'y', 'z'], '1e': ['x2', 'y2', 'z2'], 2: ['x1', 'y1', 'z1']}
```

Comment: Works for the example, but I think you need a more robust `key` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.6, `dict`s are insertion ordered. This allows us to insert keys into a `dict` in any order and have that order preserved:

```
d = {1: '[x, y, z]', 2: '[x1, y1, z1]'}
d['1e'] = '[x2, y2, z2]'

print(d)

keys = [1, '1e', 2]
d = {k:d[k] for k in keys}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: '[x, y, z]', 2: '[x1, y1, z1]', '1e': '[x2, y2, z2]'}
{1: '[x, y, z]', '1e': '[x2, y2, z2]', 2: '[x1, y1, z1]'}
```

As you can see the order has been changed to what you require.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to clean up the keys to have consistent types first.

```
>>> x, y, z, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 = (0,) * 9
>>> d = {1: [x, y, z], 2: [x1, y1, z1], '1e': [x2, y2, z2]}
>>> d2 = {str(k): v  for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d3 = {k: d2[k]  for k in sorted(d2)}
>>> d3
{'1': [0, 0, 0], '1e': [0, 0, 0], '2': [0, 0, 0]}
```